# Sheets - Lookup using 3 criteria including variable

Tags: google-sheets, match, vlookup, array-formulas

Struggling with arrayFormula and vlookup with match to reference data in another sheet tab to pull a percentage based on row and column membership.

I currently have: `=ArrayFormula(vlookup(Orange&7,{A1:A&B1:B,C1:E},match("Skill 3",A1:E1,0)-1,0))`

In the shared Google sheet, I have placed notes and explanations. This is a reference sheet for a game, where it refers to Hero skills statistics.

**MISSION**: Using inputted Hero Class "colour" and "Skill Level" get the "percentage" from the appropriate skill column. This will be needed 3 times to cater for the 3 different skill types in question.

Here is the sheet: [TEST Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k2baWk47UEe0bETOkpkUdmdRMrNOEKtSxnXcORrJPT0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach

Creating a `VLOOKUP` using more than one criteria will require a helper column made by the concatenation of the two(or more) criteria.
In your case you should build a column that concatenates the Color & Level. Your Lookup will search that value and return the corresponding percentage in the 4th column.
Having your table in Hero Lead like this:

```
+==========================================+
|  A   |  B  |  C  |   D   |   E   |   F   |
+------+-----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|Lookup|Class|Level|Skill 3|Skill 4|Skill 7|
+------------------------------------------+
```

You can use this formula to retrieve the correct value of `Skill 3`

```
=VLOOKUP("Orange"&7,'Hero Lead'!A:D,4,0)
```

Just replicate the formula with the other parameter to retrieve the correct percentage level.

Comment: I like yours better. Fixed it a bit: `=ARRAYFORMULA(
  VLOOKUP(
    C36 & "♥" & G36:G38,
    {
      'Hero Lead'!A2:A & "♥" & 'Hero Lead'!B2:B,
      'Hero Lead'!C2:E
    },
    MATCH(
      "Skill " & F36:F38,
      'Hero Lead'!$C$1:$E$1,
      0
    ) + 1,
    0
  )
)`

Comment: I didn't know the other VLOOKUP arguments. That's why i didn't use an array formula.

Comment: It looks `MATCH` is not required: `=ARRAYFORMULA(
  VLOOKUP(
    C36 & "♥" & G36:G38,
    {
      'Hero Lead'!A2:A & "♥" & 'Hero Lead'!B2:B,
      'Hero Lead'!C2:E
    },
    {2; 3; 4},
    0
  )
)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
=IFERROR(
  INDEX(
    QUERY(
      'Hero Lead'!$A$2:$E,
      "select C, D, E
       where A = '" & $C$36 & "' and
             B = " & G36,
      -1
    ),
    0,
    MATCH(
      "Skill " & F36,
      'Hero Lead'!$C$1:$E$1,
      0
    )
  ),
  0
)
```

This gets you the right skill's boost from the row filtered using `QUERY` by level and colour.

---

If you need all three at once for fixed colour and fixed level (in a column thus `TRANSPOSE`):

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  FILTER(
    'Hero Lead'!$C$2:$E,
    'Hero Lead'!$A$2:$A = $C$36,
    'Hero Lead'!$B$2:$B = G36
  )
)
```

or:

```
=TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(
    'Hero Lead'!$A$2:$E,
    "select C, D, E
     where A = '" & $C$36 & "' and
           B = " & G36,
    -1
  )
)
```